# Can one enable emails for PayPal MassPay API in sandbox mode?

Tags: paypal, masspay

It appears that when in sandbox mode, MassPay doesn't send any email. However for my test environment, where my application is making (sandbox) API calls to send money to an email address, I'd still prefer that the the email address I provide to "pay" receives the fake notification. Is there any way to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

In the sandbox, notifications are not sent to live email accounts. You can check sandbox emails when you login at https://developer.paypal.com  >> Dashboard >> Sandbox notifications

On the other hand, you can implement PayPal's IPN and use that to programmatically send out your own custom generated emails. Information on using IPN can be found at [www.paypal.com/ipn]

Comment: Yes but I am wondering if I can override the default to not send to live email accounts and actually do it